# joomla curve image problem

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am using joomla 1.5 for one of my cms projects. In the top-left corner there is a box with a curve image. But it shows a rectangle box. When I view the source using firebug its shows the curve image so please help me whats problem besides it.

my site url is
http://sunflowerhospital.in/

thanks in advance

Praveen Kalal

Comment: can u be more clear... what rectangle box around the logo are you talking about?

Comment: the box in which news are scrolling. that one

Comment: and thanks for showing your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you should seriously consider recoding all of those tables in to some clean DIVs. You've got like 5 nested tables right around the news box that makes it near impossible to tell what is going on.

Anyhow, I digress. The problem is that the image is 184px wide while your box is only 170px wide. The curves are there, but they are outside the bounds of the table.

Comment: Your image is wider than the box. Change background: url(../images/box-top.gif) no-repeat top center to this: background: url(../images/box-top.gif) no-repeat top left;

Comment: but if i use this one  background: url(../images/box-top.gif) no-repeat top left; its show the curve on left side only but not on right side we need the curve for both side

Comment: Right, you will either have to make the image smaller or the box wider.